# Change CSS background-color with PHP

Tags: php, css

I will change the background color of some table th. In my example here I used a `<div>`. 
I have a script, which seperate 2 different printing outputs in a css tab design, so it is the same website, if you change the tabs.

I want to use for every tab different backround-colors.

I have tried to add a new php variable into one class in my [print.php](https://github.com/GrischaK/french_conjugation/blob/master/print.php) file like `

```
<class="tab_new '.$css_class.'">
```

which should only have a css rule only for the backround color.

```
$css_class = 'classname1' // first case
$css_class = 'classname2' // second case
```

I will get the error PHP var $css_class is undefinied.
But the problem is, that my print.php is requiering_once before the file, where the definition of $css_class is ([verb.php](https://github.com/GrischaK/french_conjugation/blob/master/verb.php)).

Please have a look at this 2 files. Maybe my example here isn't correct for my question, but I don't know, how to explain it otherwise.

```css
.blue  {background-color:CornflowerBlue; font-weight:bold}
```

```html
<div class="blue">My backround is CornflowerBlue</div>
<br><br>
<div class="blue">My backround  should be green</div>
```

Comment: I don't see `$css_class` in print.php anywhere, but it looks like your problem is your functions. It looks like you are trying to reference a variable in global space from inside your function. Try adding `global $css_class;` to the top of the function. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: @bassxzero Thanks for your comment. I don't add the `css_class` to the github version, because it wouldn't worked anyway. I have tried to use `global $css_class` and it worked. I have updated the files on github. Is this the best solution?

Comment: I made my comment an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see `$css_class` in `print.php` anywhere, but it looks like your problem is your functions. It looks like you are trying to reference a variable in global space from inside your function. Try adding `global $css_class;` to the top of the function. php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Is this the best solution? 
IMO no. Google `dependency injection` and you will learn why it's not the best solution.

Is this the simplest solution?
Judging based on the little bit of your code I can see, then I would say probably yes.